# Change units of time dimension in NetCDF file from months to months since

Tags: r, netcdf, nco

I currently have multiple NetCDF files with 4 dimensions, (latitude, longitude, time, and depth). Each represents a single year of monthly data. The unit of time is "month", 1-12, and therefore quite useless if I want to merge these files across years to give me a single NetCDF file with a time dimension of size months*years.

The time dimension attributes for a single file:

```
time  Size:12   *** is unlimited ***
            long_nime: time
            units: month
```

I used ncrcat of nco to merge.

```
ncrcat soda3.3.1*sst.nc -O soda3.3.1_1980_2015_sst.nc
```

This works except that when merged, time values read

```
#in R
soda.info$var$temp$dim[[3]]$vals
  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  1
 [26]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  1  2
 [51]  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  1  2  3
 [76]  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  1  2  3  4
[101]  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  1  2  3  4  5
[126]  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  1  2  3  4  5  6
[151]  7  8  9 10 11 12  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
[176]  8  9 10 11 12  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
[201]  9 10 11 12  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
[226] 10 11 12  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
[251] 11 12  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
[276] 12  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
[301]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  1
[326]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  1  2
[351]  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  1  2  3
[376]  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  1  2  3  4
[401]  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  1  2  3  4  5
[426]  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
```

...which obviously isn't much help if I want to keep track of time.

In the past I've only used NetCDF files with a "months since..." unit. Is there a way to change these rather groundless 'month' units to 'months since...'?

Comment: Does this help you: https://sourceforge.net/p/nco/discussion/9830/thread/22480d31/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would it suffice to enumerate the months sequentially?

```
ncap2 -s 'time=array(0,1,$time)' soda3.3.1_1980_2015_sst.nc out.nc
```

You can also add a "months since ..." unit to time as described in the comment by Chelmy and/or in the [NCO manual](https://nco.sf.net/nco.html#ncatted). I leave that as an exercise for you, gentle reader.